# How to use re to split the column containg string combine integer without contain symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, python-re

Here is a column in df which contains integer and string both combine together.
(even here's numbers type are string)

I want split the df['symbol'] into df['num'] and df['name'],how can I do this question by re.

QUESTION:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['12345abc', '2234bcd', '323456cde'],'date':[5, 6, 7]})
```

ideal:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['12345', '2234', '323456'],
               'name':['abc','bcd','cde'],
               'date':[5, 6, 7]})
```

Thanks to instructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
df[["", "symbol", "name"]] = df["symbol"].astype(str).str.split("(\d+)", expand=True)
```

Comment: It can work ,thanks you,but I'm confuse why after split need 3 columns?

Comment: Because after splitting we are getting 3 output, first blank string then integer then name

Answer (score 0):

`split` is not the best tool for this, rather use `extract`:

```
df[['symbol', 'name']] = df['symbol'].str.extract(r'(\d+)(\D+)')
```

Output:

```
   symbol  date name
0   12345     5  abc
1    2234     6  bcd
2  323456     7  cde
```

Comment: I wonder know wht here can use r'(\d+)(\D+)'，can u help me more information?
Because I try below can't work.
 s=df["symbol"].str.split(pat="[^0-9]+(\D)+",expand=True)

Comment: If you really want to `split`, use `r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)'` as regex

Comment: txs for instructor